# Why my app is creased when i press a back button of actionBar in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I have mainActivity in which i implemented a navigationDrawer. There are multiple fragment.In first,fragment namely HomeFragment. In homeFragment i am using viewpager and listview. in my viewpager there is two things first, if match is started then it's goes to summaryCard activity. second if match no started it's goes to notstartedmatchdetail activiy.

when match is starting first i goes to summarycard activity.in summarycard activity i put the button. when i press the button in summarycard it's directly goes to fullscorecard.e.g. homeFragment->summarycard->fullscorecard.

In listview, it seen the detail of the match which was completed.Here i am directly goes to fullscorecard.e.g. homefragment->fullscorecard.

Situation:

**While i goes to homefragment->fullscorecard**

After pressing back button of fullscorecard it goes to summarycard instead of homefragment.

Here is my homeFragment where i called an adapter

```
LiveAdapter adapterTabRecent = new LiveAdapter(getContext(), lst_obj, PagerLength, list_status, lst_key);
adapterTabRecent.notifyDataSetChanged();
pagerRecentMatches.setAdapter(adapterTabRecent);
pagerRecentMatches.setCurrentItem(current_pos);


ScheduleAdapter CmAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getContext(), arr_completed, lst_key2);
CmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
completed_listview.setAdapter(CmAdapter);
```

Above both the adapter called in homefragment for started match it called liveAdapter and for completed match is called ScheduleAdapter.

Here, is my live adapter

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     String key=lst_key.get(position);
     String status_value=list_status.get(position);

     if(status_value.equals("notstarted")){
           Log.e("MATCH_KEY",""+key);
           Intent intent=new Intent(context,NotStartedMatchDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("mainobj", lst.get(position).toString());
           context.startActivity(intent);

     }
     if(status_value.equals("started")){
          Log.e("MATCH_KEY",""+key);
          MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)context;
          Intent intent=new Intent(context,SummaryCard.class);
          intent.putExtra("Key", key);
                               intent.putExtra("access_token",mainActivity.getMyData());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
         }
   }
});
```

Here is a code for listview where match is completed.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        match_key = arr_matchKey.get(position);
        Log.e("Schedule complted key", match_key);
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
        GetValue gv = new GetValue(context);
        gv.setFullUrl(match_key);
        gv.setAccessToken(activity.getMyData());
        gv.execute();
    }
});
```

Here is my manifiest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.angelnx.cricvilla.cricvilla">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotStartedMatchDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity">
            </meta-data>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SummaryCard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ScoreCard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".SummaryCard" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerInfoDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FullScore"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PlayerIccStats"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Consider fullscorecard as Scorecard in manifiest.
This problem is cause only in ice-cream sandwich lg model.
Otherwise it' working correctly in another devices.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: please show your logcat ?

Comment: Ohk wait for a minutes

Comment: There is  problem for logcat because this issue occurs in only lg mobile phone which have ice-cream sandwish OS. My lg mobile not connected to android studio.